# Expected 2 arguments but got 1 for updating firebase from ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I got a problem when try to update firebase from ionic. Here is the function when I tried to update the data.

Here is the typescript

```
updateLaporan()
  {
    this.id = this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.db.list('/laporan/'+this.id).update({
      mydate : this.mydate.value,
      porsiKarbohidrat : this.porsiKarbohidrat.value,
      porsiProteinHewani : this.porsiProteinHewani.value,
      porsiProteinNabati : this.porsiProteinNabati.value,
      porsiLemak : this.porsiLemak.value,
    })

    this.alert("Sukses update data")
  }
```

This is the html for editing the data I tried to pass the value adn receive it on ts with viewchild

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YY" [(ngModel)]="myDate" #mydate></ion-datetime>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Porsi Karbohidrat</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" #porsiKarbohidrat></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Porsi Protein Hewani</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" #porsiProteinHewani></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Porsi Protein Nabati</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="number" #porsiProteinNabati></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Porsi Lemak</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" #porsiLemak></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
  <button ion-button full (click)="updateLaporan()">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your are trying to update the object but using `this.db.list` instead.

```
updateLaporan()
  {
    this.id = this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.db.object('/laporan/'+this.id).update({
      mydate : this.mydate.value,
      porsiKarbohidrat : this.porsiKarbohidrat.value,
      porsiProteinHewani : this.porsiProteinHewani.value,
      porsiProteinNabati : this.porsiProteinNabati.value,
      porsiLemak : this.porsiLemak.value,
    })

    this.alert("Sukses update data")
  }
```